# React router to redirect new page using a button onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to allow the user to click on the "Sign up" button and be redirected to a completely new page that I can begin styling for a small project but I can't seem to figure out the react-router-dom routing correctly. Inside my App.js the components are rendered on the screen and within the Signup component there are two buttons. One "Sign up" and one "Login". My thinking is that when either button is clicked it should point the user to a new page. However, I see the correct route in the search bar being "http://localhost:5173/signup" when clicked but I do not see a new page which is frustrating because I'm not sure if I'm making the easiest mistake but I can't see it. I followed [this](https://blog.openreplay.com/routing-with-react-router-6/) code-along but I still couldn't figure out how to replicate it in my own use case for the life of me.

Here is my repo: [link](https://github.com/Kwabena2K/fitness-tracker)

Answer (score -1):

I opened your code as you have attached to your question, you might need to change here, Since you have not written any path in the Route, then how would be able to navigate there already, Following solution might help you :

```
 <Routes>
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}></Route>
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />}></Route>
      </Routes>
```

Here some changings are required too :

```
 <button
              onClick={() => navigate("/register")}
     </button>
```

Rest of your code is Fine, Happy Day!

Comment: So the signup component renders the Login and Signup button on the home screen so I don't understand why I would have to route to that component again? I'm a little confused there.


 However, for the register component, I applied the changes you mentioned for the button onclick but it is still not showing me a blank "new" page when I click the Signup button on the main page.

Comment: According to your Signup component , you only have written buttons of Login and SignUp there. You have to route every component or page you want to navigate to , According to my knowledge this is how routing works. If your register's navigation is not working yet, kindly do see the console maybe there would some errors there.

Comment: Oh okay, in the console it does says 'No routes matched location "/" ' but I'm not quite sure what that is referring to because everything regarding a route has a destination. The error is in the utils.ts file as well.

https://i.imgur.com/0Xr5XlM.png